# Is their a way to add separate CSS and JS files for a particular part of web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to add separate `CSS` and `Javascript` files those work for only particular section of a page and don't affect any other part of the page?

I am attempting to add the following to my web page:

http://codecanyon.net/item/sliderjs-js-framework-for-slider-development/full_screen_preview/1617841

When I used it, the `CSS` and `JS` files affect my whole web page.

I don't want this to be happened. I want to add a slider without changing my site totally.

Is there any way to get it working without adding all of the slider's `CSS` and `JS` code to my webpage?

Comment: Wrap that section in a tag and style everything that's descendant of that...Also look into the plugin's CSS for global styles that may be problematic.

Comment: Do you use static html or some framework ?

Comment: Please use a spell checker and proper grammer when you post. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Oh the irony! Grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to do this using an iframe as a sort of sandbox.  But it begs the question, what are you trying to "protect" the page from?  If you have name conflicts, you're best fixing those rather than sandboxing the slider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have JS and CSS specific to a certain part of a page, and you don't know JS and CSS, the only way is through iframes.

If you've made the CSS yourself, you can just add a prefix to apply it to on certain sections. Not like this:

```
p {color:pink}
```

instead, add a prefix, like this:

```
#menu p {color:pink}
#content p {color:black}
```

Your JS should only apply to elements based on id, unless your using something like jQuery. If you're using jQuery you can apply changes only to certain elements in the same way as CSS. eg.

Not like this:

```
jQuery('p').slider();
```

instead, add a prefix, like this:

```
jQuery('#content p').slider();
```

Comment: Just one more thing.. is using iframe safe for any browser compatibility ? and for mobile devices ?

Comment: @JohnKim iframes have been supported for around 10 years, so unless your client base is using IE3 it should work. Most mobile browsers have a higher compatibility than IE10 so I don't think you'll have mobile compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i will have a look over using it i hope it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes for this. Create a new page with your CSS and JS file included in it and call that page from iframe.

Comment: iframe will be good option i think... because i am preventing my whole page from being affected from the script i am installing.. and thing is i am using script that i gave url above but it has its own css and js files..